# Creating SQLite Database in Android Device and Accessing the information

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i am building an quiz application in android mobile platform.
I am creating a SQLite Database (quiz.sqlite) with pre-loaded information.

while launching the application, the database is not created inside /data/data/[PROJECT]/databases/quiz.sqlite". hence the application is crashing.

looking for logic or sample code with Database Helper.

can anyone help.

-Ranjan

Answer (score 0):

I used this c/p code adapted for my own needs to import my back up database but I needed to set permissions to read and write data on my actual device. Unfortunately I can't find the code to give credit to the original poster. You would have to create an empty database to use this method. This will then replace that database with your already created Sqlite database.

This is only one possible solution, hopefully someone can respond with an easier solution.

```
    String inFileName= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/back_up.db"; // This is where the .db file you want to load is stored on your new device
    File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception InFile: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// This was to help me define errors

    }
    String outFileName = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();// This is where Android will look for the database "/data/data/[PROJECT]/databases/quiz.sqlite"
    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception OutFile: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    try {
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Close the streams
    try {
        output.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    helper.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not an easy solve and this is not a complete solution for you. I solved the problem myself recently although more to back up and restore a Sqlite database

As a start you will need to set your read and write permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html

Comment: i have my own database and table created in the design mode. Do i need to create table in the dbhelper? please advice.